# layout.app error in laravel when setup project on local

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, setup-project

i am new in laravel my web application is properly working in online server but when i setup application on local server Then all pagess are working fine but a single page of product gives an error like this and i am not able to sole this error. It gives an error of layout.app pages shows an error message of parse error: here is an image of an error.
[This is a link of error image which shows when loading the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKbN9.jpg)

Comment: It's an unexpected end of file error. can you post your product-details.blade.php file code?

Comment: Can you share your blade file?

Comment: • Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.